# Delete File From Word Templates Startup Folder

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word

I have a template (dotm) file in the word startup folder -C:\Users(username)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP.

I want to have a macro (vba code) **in** this dotm file that delete this template from the startup folder. The template is an add-in with custom RibbonXML. I want one of my buttons to be "uninstall" button, which deletes the template file from the startup folder.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you have tried so far and why that did not work?

Comment: I have a template which is an add-in with it's own tab ribbon,
and I want one of my buttons to be "uninstall" button, which deleting the
template file from the startup folder.

Answer (score 0):

What you envision is not possible.

In order for the macro in the template to run, that template must be open or loaded as an add-in. In that case, there's a "file lock" on the template: it cannot be moved or deleted.

Deleting the template must be done from code that is not associated with the template, when the template is closed and there is no longer a file-lock.

**Edit** *based on new information edited into the question*

Possibly, code in another file could do this, although it's not certain the file lock will be released in a timely manner after the `Unload` method removes it from Word. It might require running code on a Timer to repeat the `Kill` command until it's successful.

Use the `idQ` attribute for the RibbonX tab/group that will contain the "Uninstall" button. This lets other RibbonX share the tab/group by using the same `idQ` value. Put the Ribbon XML defining that button, as well as the code for it, in the other file. When both files' Ribbons are loaded it will appear to the user as one Ribbon.

The startup template would load this other file as an add-in using the method `Application.AddIns.Add`.

Comment: is it possible to open another code from another file, which close the template (and unlock it), and then delete it?

Comment: @oriziv I've supplemented my response, based on your other comment. Please note that such information belongs *in the question*, so that others understand exactly what you're asking.